# Overfull \vbox (7.96234pt too high) has occurred while \output is active

Tags: header-footer

I put a figure in a new page and I got the following message:

```
Overfull \vbox (7.96234pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

The log file shows the following:

```
Overfull \vbox (7.96234pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.47046
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046
..\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
..\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046, glue set 466.20738fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
..\pdfcolorstack 0 pop


[1

]
Overfull \vbox (7.96234pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.47046
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046
..\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
..\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046, glue set 462.9443fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
..\pdfcolorstack 0 pop


[2

]
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <figures/logo.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-03-10 17:02:38
(epstopdf)                    size: 106887 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <figures/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-11-06 11:26:23
(epstopdf)                    size: 11686 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=figures/logo-eps-converted
-to.pdf figures/logo.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 152.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
<figures/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=167, 113.42375pt x 127.47626pt>
File: figures/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use figures/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 152.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 85.35826pt x 95.93373pt.

Overfull \vbox (7.96234pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.47046
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046
..\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
..\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046, glue set 459.68123fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
...\T1/cmr/m/n/12 i
..\pdfcolorstack 0 pop


There are many such messages! which I am trying to get rid of.

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Examination}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.01cm}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = 3cm]{figures/logo.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\noindent \nonumber` isn't doing anything, do you need a figure environment at all if you have no caption? You haven't shown the relevant part of the log so it isn't clear that that figure is generating the overfull message (normally overfull boxes in output routines are in the page head). Add `\showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen` to your preamble then the log file will show the contents of the overfull box

Comment: yes, \noindent \nonumber isn't doing anything. Thanks for pointing that. I am editing the post with output from \showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen

Comment: the message seems to appear on every page, with a report of `.\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046` which looks very like a running head, as suggested by david carlisle.  take a look at how that is defined, and at the value of `\headheight`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The box shows that it is the page number `i` then `ii` you have not shown any example code that shows where this page number is being set but it will be either the page head or foot. Assuming this is the page head, a height of 0pt is has been specified for the head hence

```
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.47046
      ^^^^
```

But of course the letters are taller than that, in particular they are `7.96234pt` high

```
..\hbox(7.96234+0.0)x469.47046, glue set 462.9443fil
```

so your headheight needs to be at least that much. So you need to increase

```
  \setlength\headheight{10pt}
```

should be enough, but better work out why this is being set to 0 in the first place and correct that code.